# `firebase` throws error on fetching data from server

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I am  trying to fetch data from `firebase` using `angularfire`, but i thrown error as `TypeError: $firebaseArray.$loaded is not a function`. how to fix this?

here is my factory module:

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("tcpApp")
        .factory("server", ['$resource','$firebaseArray', function ($resource, $firebaseArray) {

            var projectsData = new Firebase("https://tcp.firebaseio.com/projects");

            $firebaseArray.$loaded(projectsData).then(function (data) {

                console.log(data);

            })


            //return $resource('http://localhost:2403/projects/:id', {id:'@id'});

        }]);

})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you initialize a `$firebaseArray`. Instead:

```
var projectsData = new Firebase("https://tcp.firebaseio.com/projects");

$firebaseArray(projectData).$loaded(projectsData).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Please take a moment to follow the [AngularFire quickstart and programming guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/index.html), as both will save you much time with problems like this.

That documentation will also show [the best way for monitoring the loading of data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html#section-async-intro). Instead of `$loaded`+`console.log`, bind the `$firebaseArray` to the scope:

```
var projectsData = new Firebase("https://tcp.firebaseio.com/projects");

$scope.projects = $firebaseArray(projectData)
```

And then in your view HTML, show it like this:

```
<pre>{{ projects | json }}</pre>
```

*In general there is hardly ever a need for `$loaded`. It will only trigger once, when the initial contents of the array have loaded. But `$firebaseArray` is a synchronized array, that may be updated many times after the initial load and `$loaded` will not fire for those subsequent updates.*